# How to avoid ImageList localization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, imagelist

I wonder if there is the possibility to avoid ImageList localization in VisualStudio, this is an annoying thing for many reasons:

1. ImageList localization blows up my complex winfors very often, I don't know why but the problem is definetly on ImageList, I had to create a tool that removes the ImageStream from my localized resources in order to open correctly the form in the designer.
2. The size of compiled resources grows
3. If I add an image on the default language I have to switch all the languages to add it or I have to run my tool to remove ImageStream from resources

The same question can be asked for some UserControl properties (such as usercontrol with images that should not change).

I use C# but I think that this behavior is the same for all .NET languages.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you to use resources instead of ImageList. I know that ImageList like his name suggest is for images but I think this is a very bad control from Microsoft full of memory leak like you said. In the vast majority of cases, images are the same in English vs other languages. In a case where you have a different image, you just have to set it again in resource files.